# ¿Cómo puedo quitar "timezone_type" y "timezone" de mi JSON?

Tags: php, sql-server, json, sql-server-2014

En mi funcion toJSON() despliego ciertos valores en ellos un datetime.
Ejemplo:

```
 "gps": [
    {
        "serie": "12345",
        "name": "MasterK10",
        "dateUpdate": {
            "date": "2018-07-04 00:00:00.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
        } 
]
```

Quiero que solo se despliegue así:

```
"gps": [
        {
            "serie": "12345",
            "name": "MasterK10",
            "dateUpdate": "2018-07-04 00:00:00.000000",
    ]
```

Agrego mi metodo y la imagen de la consulta en SQL-Server

```
public function toJson() {
    return json_encode(array(
        'serie' => $this->serie,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'dateUpdate' => $this->dateUpdate,
        'location' => json_decode($this->location->toJson()),
        'status' => $this->status
    ));
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me funcionó con este código:

```
'dateUpdate ' => date_format($this->dateUpdate , 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías obtener el array `$this->dateUpdate`y asignar otra variable con la string, de tal manera que quede tal que así:

```
public function toJson() {
    $dateUpdateArray = $this->dateUpdate;
    //Asignamos otra variable
    $dateUpdateString = $dateUpdateArray['date'];
    return json_encode(array(
        'serie' => $this->serie,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'dateUpdate' => $dateUpdateString,
        'location' => json_decode($this->location->toJson()),
        'status' => $this->status
    ));
}
```

Comment: De esa manera el resultado final sería:
``
 "gps": [
    {
        "serie": "12345",
        "name": "MasterK10",
        "dateUpdate": {
            "date": "2018-07-04 00:00:00.000000"
        } 
]
``

Comment: He editado la pregunta, prueba asi @CarlosRamosar

Comment: Me apareció el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type DateTime as array in gps.php:162 .

Comment: En tu código, puedes hacer un var_dump() a `$this->dateUpdate` y el resultado añadirlo a la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder a la propiedad `dateUpdate.update` directamente de esta manera:

```
   public function toJson() {
    return json_encode(array(
        'serie' => $this->serie,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'dateUpdate' => $this->dateUpdate['date'],
        'location' => json_decode($this->location->toJson()),
        'status' => $this->status
    ));
}
```

Espero que te sirva, un saludo

Comment: Me apareció el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type DateTime as array in gps.php:162 .